# Liquid Templating: Truncate N paragraphs

Tags: liquid, templating

In [Liquid](http://liquidmarkup.org/), I'm aware you can do
`{% content | truncate:64 %}` to truncate 64 characters and `{% content | truncatewords:100 %}` to truncate 100 words, but is there any way to truncate by a given number of *paragraphs*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Maybe you can do something like this:

```
{% assign truncatedContent = '' %}
{% assign paragraphs = post.content | split:'</p>' %}
{% for paragraph in paragraphs limit:N %}
    {{ truncatedContent | append: paragraph }}
    {{ truncatedContent | append: '</p>' }}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Absolutely spot on, nice one.